# How to hide a page in the Tree view in doxygen documentation?

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation

I am currently documenting my code with doxygen. But I encountered a little problem. I would like to show some UML diagrams on an extra pages, just for readability. But when I create a `\page` and reference to it on the main page with `\subpage` It also appears in the tree view left.
Now to my question: Is it possible to hide pages from the tree view?

```
/*! \mainpage Documentation
 * \section intro Introduction
 * 
 * 
 * \subpage uml1
 * 
 * 
 */  


/*! \page uml1 First UML diagram
 * 
 * \startuml
 * 
 * \enduml
 */
```

Comment: In the section "Changing the layout of pages" there is something about changing the layout and it is also possible to define own pages etc. I don't know if this will bring something in this case (disclaimer: I never really used the layout file and never used self defined parts here).

Comment: @albert I know what you mean. I read about it too. But I just found how to disable whole tree view, not deleting an entry or something. I defined a own page, that is what the code in my question is doing.